# C++ library in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have made a c++ project in CodeBlocks. Now I started using Visual Studio Code and I can't figure out how to connect files. I have `main.cpp` with my main code, then I have `sortlib.cpp` with some sorting functions and I have `sortlib.h`. My question is how do I connect these files, so I can `#include "sortlib.h"` in my `main.cpp` file and use the functions.
I have tried including `sortlib.h` in my `sortlib.cpp` program and then my `sortlib.h` in my `main.cpp` program, but it didn't work.

I'm on windows so I just compiled my `sortlib.cpp` program by typing `g++ sortlib.cpp` and it showed me this error message
`c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and define "didn't work".  And please provide the exact compilation commands that get run.

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting `undefined reference to ...` because you only compile `main.cpp`, right?

Comment: No, i compiled everything.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `tasks.json` since likely your bug is there and you had to modify it in several different ways to compile your project successfully. The default `tasks.json` will not work as it assumes you have a single source file and no external libraries.

Comment: How are you compiling everything? Show the exact command(s) like @StephenNewell asked for and include the full error message you get.

Comment: You can click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66641554/edit) to add information to the question.

Comment: I'm sorry im new to all of this so i don't really know how everything works. I'm on windows so i just compiled my "sortlib.cpp" program by typing g++ sortlib.cpp and it showed me this error message c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xc0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'

Comment: If you are not building from inside VSCode by correctly setting up your `tasks.json` and pressing F5 or ctrl-F5 you need to type all the source file names on the g++ command. With that said the `WinMain@16` error is one you can search. Its a common problem. Does `sortlib.cpp` have your `int main()`?

Comment: If you want to build from the VSCode IDE directly and you are not using `CMake` or a `Makefile` or similar the change you need to make in `tasks.json` is in the documenatation here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: @krystof That is information that should have been in the question, not as a comment. I put it in the question for you this time but next time, just click [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66641554/edit) under your question to update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Minimal code structure

#### `main.cpp`

```cpp
// Other header files
#include "sortlib.h"

int main(void) {
  ...
}
```

#### `sortlib.h`

```cpp
void someFunction();
...
```

#### `sortlib.cpp`

```cpp
// Include headers that are required

void someFunction() {
  ...
}
```

### The minimal required command

```
g++ -g main.cpp sortlib.cpp
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as "connecting" files in programming. You have to make sure that your compiler is compiling all the .cpp files into .o/.obj files and that they are all getting linked together to produce your final executable.